# Changing Javascript variable value after onclick action

Tags: javascript, html

Pretty new to this Javascript thing.

I want to change a Javascript variable when a user inserts a number into an input field in my HTML document and clicks a button.

I'm assuming you'd use a function, but how do you gather the data and change the variable?

The stuff I tried to make looks a little something like this.

**HTML**

```
<input type="number" id="inputField">
<button onclick="changeTheVariable()" type="button" id="pushMe"></button>
```

**Javascript**

```
var a = 0;
function changeTheVariable() {
   a = document.getElementById("inputField").value;
}
```

but it's not working!

**Edit 1:**

Wow. I didn't think I'd get this kind of attention. I also found it a bit strange it didn't work at first.

The question I'm asking is partly for a calculator here: https://titomagic.com/debug

It's simple, you type in a number, click the button and it calculates (based on other variables) to a result on the bottom.

Here's a link to the Javascript file, if you wanna have a look: https://titomagic.com/js/bursdagskalkulator.js

To those of you asking; yes, I've been testing with a console.log and the variable is not changing. It's not affecting the other variables (as it should?).

Also I've never heard of JSfiddle.

Comment: your code is working..Can you add a fiddle it would be helpful

Comment: How you confirmed that value of `a` didn't change?

Comment: This code work as is ... voting to close

Comment: It seems correct. Use `console.log(a)` inside your function to verify that it is changing.

Comment: weird...I just jsfiddled it...and it's not working, and I agree it should be working

Comment: the code works fine on your site. it's console.logging the value when i click on the button.

Comment: It's not changing the result, though. The bottom h1 is connected to a rule that uses variable gjesterTotalt (see line 28) that's depending on the value being filled in the input field to change variable antallGjester. If my function is supposed to work, then it should change the number on the bottom. It's all supposed to be connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered few things in the `summarizeGjester()` function. First of all I moved all the Javascript code in the *bursdagskalkulator.js* file inside the `summarizeGjester()` function.  Also I converted `var antallGjester` to integer using [parseInt()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) function, because it was treated as string before.

```
 var antallGjester = document.getElementById("gjesterAntallInput").value;
 antallGjester = parseInt(antallGjester);  //integer conversion
```

Also the first Boolean comparison was changed to
`if ((antallGjester < 10) && (antallGjester > 0))`, so that the second one would work if there’s 0 value: `else if (antallGjester === 0)`.

```js
 function summarizeGjester() {

    var antallGjester = document.getElementById("gjesterAntallInput").value;

    antallGjester = parseInt(antallGjester);

    var fastPris = 1500;

    var fastPrisDifferanse = 10;

    var gjestePris = 120;

    var gjesteDifferanse = antallGjester - fastPrisDifferanse;

    var gjesteSum = gjestePris * gjesteDifferanse;

    var gjesterTotalt = 0;

    if ((antallGjester < 10) && (antallGjester > 0)) {
      console.log("antallGjester < 10");
      gjesterTotalt = 1500;
    } else if (antallGjester === 0) {
      console.log("antallGjester === 0");
      gjesterTotalt = 0;
    } else {
      console.log("else");
      gjesterTotalt = fastPris + gjesteSum;
    }

    document.querySelector('#results').innerHTML = gjesterTotalt;
  }
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="gjesterAntall">Antall barn:</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="gjesterAntallInput">
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" onclick="summarizeGjester()" type="button" id="sumGjester">Legg sammen</button>
</form>

<h1 class="text-center" style="font-size:80px;"><strong><span id="results">0</span>,-</h1>
```

I hope this helps :-)

Comment: This did it! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

### HTML

```
<input type="number" id="inputField" ClientIDMode="static">
<button onclick="changeTheVariable()" type="button" id="pushMe"></button>
```

### Javascript

```
var a = 0;
function changeTheVariable() {
   a = document.getElementById('inputField').value;
   alert(a);
}
```

Use Static ClientIDMode for stable id and access after page rendering
PlaceHolders canh change childe's id

Answer (score -2):

I suppose this will work for you

```js
var a = 0;
function changeTheVariable() {
   a = document.getElementById("inputField").value || a;
   document.getElementById("result").innerText = parseFloat(a);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="inputField">
<button onclick="changeTheVariable()" type="button" id="pushMe">Click me</button>
<div>Result: <span id="result"></span></div>
```

**Edited:**

The reason behind this code is not running in jsfiddle is here.
[image]

After making the `changeTheVariable()` global variable this code will work in jsfiddle also. Here https://jsfiddle.net/1b9cfmje/

Use the following javascript code:

```
window.onload = function(){ var a = 0; window.changeTheVariable = function() {  a = document.getElementById("inputField").value || a; document.getElementById("result").innerText = parseFloat(a); }}
```